# javascript - How to clip using drawImage/putImageData

Tags: javascript, html, image, canvas, clipping

I'm writing an application that needs static clipping for images on the canvas (as you move the images on the canvas the clipping area stays in one place). I have three cases: polygon, ellipse, any shape specified with an image. I was able to cope with polygon and ellipse, because I can do them with paths and arcs, but when it comes to a mask specified via an image I'm not sure what to do.

Example shape to clip to:
[Let's say I am not able to draw it using paths](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y6kzI.png)

So I have it specified with an image, I know how to obtain image data from it. **What I'm trying to achieve is to clip everything that is out of that figure.**

I was trying like this:

```
canvas.clipTo = function (ctx) {
    ctx.drawImage(shape.src, left, top);
};
```

And like this:

```
canvas.clipTo = function (ctx) {
    ctx.putImageData(imgData, left, top);
};
```

Of course none of them work as I expect, it just draws that black shape instead of clipping to that region.

Any ideas how to do it?

Comment: Your mask appears to be opaque black shape on opaque white background. Is this what you intend or is your actual mask transparent instead of white?

Answer (score 0):

I do it by creating a new canvas the same size as the mask image. Then draw the image on that canvas, then set the `ctx.globalCompositeOperation` to `"destination-in"` draw the mask over the image (masking it) , then draw the that canvas to the on-screen canvas with `ctx.drawImage`

As this is most definitely a duplicated question I will not give the answer as code, it's been done to death here on stackoverflow.

Oh and I forgot. Using imageData to clip is a very inefficient way to do it.

Comment: The masking .png appears to be fully opaque. That's hopefully a mistake by the questioner or possibly the white background needs to be knocked out.